# Puff.c How do I create the defalte stream that will work

Tags: gzip, zlib, deflate

I'm using Zlib to deflate a series of arrays using compress.  My test code uses uncompress and works correctly.  Here's my question:

Can I use Zlib compress my array so that it can be uncompressed using **puff.c**.  Puff.c is available in a much larger application and I do not have the option of installing Zlib as a library.

I ran pufftest.c with zero.raw successfully, but **How do I create zeros.raw**

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow take a tour Go through [How to Ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps you for more views and some Answers

Answer (score 0):

"raw" means no zlib header or trailer. You can simply strip the two-byte header and four-byte trailer from the output of compress to feed to puff. Better would be to process the zlib header and trailer (documented in [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)), and feed the deflate innards to puff. Then the trailer provides an integrity check on the uncompressed data, as was intended.

Comment: I found this in a C# document and It worked.  Not for nothing, but this small nugget could be added as a note in pufftest.